# NSIS change installer language

Tags: nsis

I want to ask a question how to change the installer language.

This is what i wrote in the code:

```
LoadLanguageFile "${NSISDIR}\Contrib\Language files\Romanian.nlf"
```

Now I loaded it, but how to run it?

Comment: You need to load more than one .nlf, loading just one means only that language so there is nothing to change...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set `$Language` with `StrCpy` in `.onInit`.

This is usually done with `MUI_LANGDLL_DISPLAY` or the [LangDll plugin](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Examples/languages.nsi) so that the user can choose from a list of languages.

NSIS will try to use the "best match" language as the default...

Comment: I see, but where should I write them and how (I am a noob)

Comment: What link are you talking about?